# WASI-libc wait for user input when writing to stdin

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I would like to implement [`fd_read`](https://github.com/WebAssembly/WASI/blob/main/phases/snapshot/docs.md#fd_read) from the WASI API by waiting for the user to type some text in an HTML `input` field, and then continuing with the rest of the WASI calls. I.e., with something like:

```js
fd_read = (fd, iovs, iovsLen, nread) => {
    // only care about 'stdin'
    if(fd !== STDIN)
        return WASI_ERRNO_BADF;

    const encoder = new TextEncoder();

    const view = new DataView(memory.buffer);
    view.setUint32(nread, 0, true);

    // create a UInt8Array for each buffer
    const buffers = Array.from({ length: iovsLen }, (_, i) => {
        const    ptr = iovs + i * 8;
        const    buf = view.getUint32(ptr, true);
        const bufLen = view.getUint32(ptr + 4, true);

        return new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, buf, bufLen);
    });

    // get input for each buffer
    buffers.forEach(buf => {
        const input = waitForUserInput();

        buf.set(encoder.encode(input));
        view.setUint32(nread, view.getUint32(nread, true) + input.length, true);
    });
    
    return WASI_ESUCCESS;
}
```

The implementation works if the variable `input` is provided. For example, setting `const input = "1\n"` passes that string to a `scanf` call in my C program, and it reads in a value of `1`.

However, I'm struggling to "stop" the JavaScript execution while waiting for the input to be provided. I understand that JavaScript is event-driven and can't be "paused" in the traditional sense, but trying to provide the input as a callback/Promise has the problem of the function still executing, causing nothing to get passed to `stdin`:

```js
buffers.forEach(buf => {
    let input;

    waitForUserInput().then(value => {
        input = value;
    });

    buf.set(encoder.encode(input));
    view.setUint32(nread, view.getUint32(nread, true) + input.length, true);
});
```

Since input is still waiting to be set, nothing gets encoded in the buffer and `stdin` just reads a `0`.

Is there a way to wait for the input with `async`/`await`, or maybe a "hack-y" solution with `setTimeout`? I know that `window.Prompt()` would stop the execution, but I want the input to be a part of the page. Looking for vanilla JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Thank you for providing the implementation of fd_read, this is what I have been looking for. Yet I am a bit puzzled about the rule for creating those buffers specifically: `iovs + i * 8`. Why 8? Is there any specification on how to implement fd_read somewhere? I want to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

You want to connect asynchronous JavaScript APIs to synchronous WebAssembly APIs. This is a common problem for which WebAssembly itself doesn't yet have a built-in solution, but there are some at the tooling level. In particular, you might want to take a look at Asyncify - I've written a detailed post on how it helps solve those use-cases and how to use it here: https://web.dev/asyncify/

Particularly for WASI, the post also showcases a demo that connects `fd_read` and other synchronous operations to async APIs from File System Access. You can find live demo at https://wasi.rreverser.com/ and its code at https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/wasi-fs-access.

For example, here is an implementation of the `fd_read` function you're interested in, that uses async-await to wait for asynchronous API: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/wasi-fs-access/blob/4c2d29fdfe79abb9b48bd44e296c2019f55d0eec/src/bindings.ts#L449-L461

You should be able to adapt same approach, Asyncify tooling and potentially even the same code to your example using `setTimeout` or input events.